# ObjCMongoDB Linker Error

Tags: ios, objcmongodb

I am attempting to build a very basic iPad app that connects to a hosted instance of MongoDB at mongohq.com. After some research, it seems that the [ObjCMongoDB](https://github.com/paulmelnikow/ObjCMongoDB) library will suit my needs nicely. However, after following the install instructions/commentary [here](https://github.com/paulmelnikow/ObjCMongoDB/wiki/GettingStarted) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16466982/objcmongodb-broken-i-cant-get-it-to-work) I am unable to build. The compiler is complaining with the following errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSAttributeDescription", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in NSManagedObject+BSONCoding.o

_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSEntityDescription", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in NSManagedObject+BSONCoding.o

_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSFetchedPropertyDescription", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in NSManagedObject+BSONCoding.o

_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSManagedObject", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in NSManagedObject+BSONCoding.o

_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_NSManagedObject_$_BSONCoding in NSManagedObject+BSONCoding.o

_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSRelationshipDescription", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in NSManagedObject+BSONCoding.o

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

As a novice iOS developer, I suspect either a) I have installed it incorrectly or b) I am mistaken in my basic understanding of the library. For reference, I have checked out `v0.9.7`, run `git submodule update --init` and `git submodule sync` from the command line in the repo's folder. Thanks in advance for any and all guidance.

**UPDATE**

It appears that the .o file extensions are indicative of the compiler trying to build a Mac app, not an iPad app. Perhaps there is a setting or flag I am missing in the library to build for iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to link against Core Data. Try adding `CoreData.framework` to your target's **Link Binary with Libraries** section.

Or, if you don't need Core Data serialization, just remove `NSManagedObject+BSONCoding.[hm]` from your target and/or project. The rest of ObjCMongoDB will work just fine without it.

Comment: Adding the `CoreData.framework` did the trick. Many thanks for the answer and a very helpful library.